# Python 2.7 - Differences when writing to a file on Win7 vs OSX

Tags: python, windows, macos, python-2.7

I've been writing a program that reads in a file, and changes specific characters before writing it again. When I run the program under OSX, the output is exactly as I would like. However, when trying to run it under Windows, the written file has a number of unintended characters sprinkled in the file. If I check the length of the output in Python before I write it, it's the intended size, so I assume something is different with the Python writing protocol on Windows. Here's a snippet of the code if you're interested.

```
    rom = open(rom_name, 'rb').read()
    rom_list = list(rom)
    for item in ability_locations:
        address = int(item, 16)
        rand_ind = random.randint(0,len(ability_values) - 1)
        new_enemy = ability_values[rand_ind]
        new_enemy = chr(int(new_enemy,16))
        rom_list[address] = new_enemy
    rom = "".join(rom_list)
    new_rom = open(rom_name.split(".")[0] + "_" + str(KA_seed) + ".nes", 'w')
    new_rom.write(rom)
    new_rom.close()
```

It might be worth noting that I'm attempting to modify a hex file, so many of the characters are "unusual". I don't know if writing some of these characters might be the problem.

I'd appreciate any help you can give me. Thanks!

Edit: For future people having the same issue, writing in binary mode fixed my issue ('wb' instead of 'w').

Comment: write in binary mode `"wb"`.

Comment: Wow, yep that did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows inserts carrage-return chars, when writing in text mode. Write your file in binary mode `"wb"`:

```
with open(rom_name, 'rb') as rom:
    rom = rom.read()
rom_list = list(rom)
for item in ability_locations:
    address = int(item, 16)
    new_enemy = random.choice(ability_values)
    rom_list[address] = chr(int(new_enemy, 16))
with open('{}_{}.new'.format(rom_name.split(".")[0], KA_seed), 'wb') as new_rom:
    new_rom.write("".join(rom_list))
```

Comment: It's not Windows per se, because `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` work with binary files. It's the C runtime's implementation of text mode on Windows. It also interprets Ctrl+Z (i.e. `'\x1a'`) as EOF, which could surprise someone when reading a file in text mode. Notably Python 3 doesn't use the CRT's text mode and doesn't emulate this Ctrl+Z nonsense (except when reading from the console) that was inherited from CP/M.